# Is GridGain Data Grid supported on IBM AIX?

Tags: aix, gridgain

We are evalutating various Data Grid solutions. 
Is GridGain supported on IBM AIX (so IBM JVM) ?
I could not figure out from the web site.

Regards,
Sebastien.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GridGain is currently being ran in several IBM AIX deployments.